# NDSolve::bvdae error when using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to solve this complex problem.

```
NDSolve[{-((f1'[t] + f2'[t] + f3'[t])/t) + 1/4 (f1'[t] f2'[t] + f1'[t] f3'[t] + f2'[t] f3'[t]) == 0, 
1/4 f2'[t] f3'[t] - (f2'[t] + f3'[t])/t + 1/4 (f2'[t]^2 + f3'[t]^2) + 1/2 (f2''[t] + f3''[t]) == 0, 
1/4 f1'[t] f3'[t] - (f1'[t] + f3'[t])/t + 1/4 (f1'[t]^2 + f3'[t]^2) + 1/2 (f1''[t] + f3''[t]) == 0, 
f1[0] == 0, f2[0] == 0, f3[0] == 0, f1[-10] == 5, f2[-10] == 0, f3[-10] == 0},
{f1, f2, f3}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

*Mathematica* showing me this error:

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.
NDSolve::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems.
```

Can anyone please take a look into this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have 3 unknown functions, 2 equations of order 2, 1 equation of order 1 and 2 boundary conditions per unknown function; for an ODE, one needs 3 equations of order 2 (or fewer boundary conditions?). So _Mathematica_ cannot treat the problem as ODE and thus is forced to treat it as DAE. Alas, your problem is also a boundary value problem (two boundary conditions per unknown function but _at different times_). And _Mathematica_ cannot handle boundary value problems for DAE.

Comment: Also, the system is singular at the BC at `t == 0`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Got it.